# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in Teamcity

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, teamcity

I am building a web api in asp.net, and using Teamcity for CI, I made a build configuration which contains restore, build and run unit tests steps. I encountered the problem when I created a new class library in my solution dedicated to Unit Tests (using XUnit) and added a reference to my main csproj. On locally the build success but after check-in the Build Log in Teamcity throw the following at build step:

> [Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018: The "GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles" task failed unexpectedly. [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\Dell.DFS.Services.API.runtimeconfig.json' because it is being used by another process. [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options) [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles.WriteToJsonFile(String fileName, Object value) [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles.WriteRuntimeConfig(ProjectContext projectContext) [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles.ExecuteCore() [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]
>
> [01:40:30][Step 2/5] C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(155,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__25.MoveNext() [D:\BuildAgent\work\8967de193f3f8a62\Dell.DFS.Services.API\Dell.DFS.Services.API.csproj]

Reverting, every time I delete the reference from my test csproj, the build pass after check-in, but I actually need it. Anyone knows how to deal with this?